# Coloring glyphicon separately

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I would like to coloring 1 glyphs separately if it's possible, somehow.
Coloring every little square of this glyphs called "glyphicon-th-large" from the Bootstrap framework.

Comment: No...it's not possible. The glyph is a **single character** not separate elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `style="color:red" // or anything else`

```
<a style="color:red"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span></a>
```

Comment: I mean to coloring the 4 little squar, part by part. Just like here in this logo:
http://growiee.com/img/partners/envienta.png

Comment: Thats not possible by using glyph icons, you should use 4 separate divs each one containing different color and different icon inside them. like this https://jsfiddle.net/La6xk76a/

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the, I confess, unclear, question. I think the OP wants to color different parts of a **single** icon..which is clearly impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You use classes to pick glyphicons, and `glyphicon-th-large` is the class of that particular icon.
Simply add a style to `.glyphicon-th-large` and every time you use that icon, it will have the color you choose.

This is the style you should use (changing the color red whatever color you want):

```
.glyphicon-th-large{
    color: red;
}
```